# Admob Interstitial ad shows after three end games

Tags: xcode, session, admob, ads, interstitial

How do i limit Admob interstitial ads to show only once after my game session has ended three times? I am try to limit amount of the ads annoying players. I am using Xcode, thanks.

Comment: A variable to count how many times the game has ended...?

Answer (score 0):

Just set a counter that keeps track of the number of time a game is played,  then on every 3 times, present it and reset counter

pseudo code
    init:
       adMobCounter = 3;

```
gameEnd:
    adMobCounter--;
    if(adMobCounter == 0)
    {
        adMobInterstitialPresent();
        adMobCounter = 3;
    }
```